# Can't find certain apps from different PCs

Tags: windows-8, windows-store

I downloaded a few apps from MS Store, like [MetroPass Free](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/metropass-free/fa0bacf9-32f3-4036-8f38-327cb7c22bee) and [VK App](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/55677f7c-3dab-4a57-95b2-4efd44a0e692) to my laptop.

Today I wanted to download them on my dekstop PC too. Searching them via Store app only leads to unwanted results, like Solitaire games. Even searching for "metropass" leads to only one result "Word Search Saga".

Eventually I had to browse Windows Store website to install my favourite apps.
This happens, at the current time, on a single PC only. How to fix Store search?

Comment: If you use the same Microsoft account your Apllications will automatically sync provided that option is enabled you can install apps from the store on I belive its 99 devices

Comment: I didn't enable that, willingly. I haven't (yet) accepted the answer below because I cannot believe Windows Store works so bad! But that seems the only way so far

Comment: It's not bad; I suspect the reason is becaue of the language or region the pc appears to be from, not all applications, are offered to all countries.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend that if you sign in to the machine with the same Microsoft Account, simply go to the store and click on `Account` at the top, then `My Apps`.

There is a filter that shows all apps on your account that are not currently installed on your machine.

[image]